# How to set the default for non translated strings in a ResourceBundle?

Tags: java, resources

I need to change the default behaviour of the java resource bundles.
Default behaviour is to use the default language file, if a key is not available in the current language.

All of my ressourceBundles are loaded via `ResourceBundle.getBundle(...)`, and I am not able to change this.

I need to change the default to use the key instead of the default language value.
Example: `mb.properties` contains `hello.string = hello world`, the current locale uses the file `mb_de.properties` which does not contain the key `hello.string`. Calling `getString("hello.string")` should return "hello.string" instead of "hello world".

So how to write a custom resource bundle wrapper where I can implement this functionality?

Comment: Are you saying you want the default value to be the key, not any bundle’s defined value?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: Are you trying to alter the behavior of ResourceBundle.getBundle calls which are not in your power to directly change?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the resoursebundle this way

```
public class CustomResourceBundle_en extends ResourceBundle {


    public CustomResourceBundle_en() {
        setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages_en"));
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        if (parent.keySet().contains(key)) {
            return parent.getObject(key);
        } else {
            return key;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration getKeys() {
        return parent.getKeys();
    }

}
```

then another for en locale for example

```
public class CustomResourceBundle_it extends CustomResourceBundle_en {
    public CustomResourceBundle_it() {
        setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages_it"));
    }
}
```

create the two properties files 
**message_en.properties**

```
hello.world=Hello World
```

**message_it.properties**  leave empty

and then use it this way

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("CustomResourceBundle", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(messages.getString("hello.world"));
```

it will print *Hello world* otherwise with locale it

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("CustomResourceBundle", Locale.ITALIAN);
    System.out.println(messages.getString("hello.world"));
```

it will print the key *hello.world*